# Kernel dies whenever importing tensorflow version 1.12.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using win 7, 64 bit, 4 GB RAM. Whenever i import tensorflow, the kernel dies and restarts automatically. My installed tensorflow version is 1.12.0 and spyder version is 3.2.8 and python is 3.6.5. Is it something related to version compatibility or some other issue. My google search says people have experienced it on Jupyter mostly.

What could be the solution please?

Comment: try running a plain Py file instead. in your same environment.

Comment: Hi Curcuma, thanks for reply.Kindly can you elaborate a further

Comment: export in Py format, then run Python yourfile.py

Comment: i am already running it as py file

Comment: well, you mentioned Jupyter, it's quite different, still, not sure if this is caused by Jupyter as if happens when you just import, I think, you should check your Cuda, Nvidia driver, and your TF version, if you are using tensorflow-gpu

Comment: Curcuma, thanks alot for the help. I was able to resolve the issue by re-installing python and updating all using conda....